# Need to add autorize payment gateway in wordpress woo commerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I need to integrate authorize payment gateway in wordpress woo commerce.

I have referred https://github.com/AuthorizeNet link for that.

But there is no solution.

Can anybody help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post the code you have written and tell us what does not work?

Comment: There is plugin.I got the plugin.Thank you @Chirag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to install below plugin.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/authorizenet-payment-gateway-for-woocommerce/

Add merchant id & login id.

Work perfectly